# Failed to get mails by using javax.mail.Folder.getMessages()

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I used `javax.mail` to get mails, but got nothing.

```
    private void init(Properties prop) {
    log.info("Initializing. ");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop);
    try {
        store = session.getStore(protocol);

    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e){
        log.error("Failed to initialize! " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    try {
        store.connect(host, username, password);
        folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
    } catch (AuthenticationFailedException e){
        log.error("Failed to login. ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e){
        log.error("Cannot connect to the host. ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here I'm sure that the mailbox can be connected correctly.

```
public Message[] receiveMessages(Date start, Date end){
    log.info("Getting mails from " + start + " to " + end + " it's " + ((end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / 1000) + "seconds. ");
    Message[] messages = null;
    SearchTerm termStart = new SentDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GT, start);
    SearchTerm termEnd = new SentDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.LE, end);
    SearchTerm term = new AndTerm(termStart, termEnd);
    try{
        messages = folder.search(term);
        log.info("Got " + messages.length + " mail(s)");
    } catch (MessagingException e){
        log.error("Failed to get mails. ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return messages;
}
```

Here, `messages.length` is `0`. But there are some mails in the mailbox during specified time.

```
2020-05-13 15:54:32.287  INFO 3878 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.u.mailOrder.util.MailConfigXML         : Initializing. 
2020-05-13 15:54:32.349  INFO 3878 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.u.mailOrder.config.XMLToMailConfig     : Get users = helong
2020-05-13 15:54:32.349  INFO 3878 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.u.mailOrder.config.XMLToMailConfig     : Get users = wanghai
2020-05-13 15:54:32.349  INFO 3878 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.u.mailOrder.config.XMLToMailConfig     : Get users = zhuhaishan
2020-05-13 15:54:32.349  INFO 3878 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.u.mailOrder.util.MailConfigXML         : Try to connect to mailbox: security_device@bmac.sec。
2020-05-13 15:54:32.350  INFO 3878 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.u.mailOrder.util.MailConfigXML         : users = [helong, wanghai, zhuhaishan]
2020-05-13 15:54:32.350  INFO 3878 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.u.mailOrder.util.MailConfigXML         : Initializing. 
2020-05-13 15:54:32.369  INFO 3878 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.u.mailOrder.job.GetMailAndProcess      : agentId = 1000059
2020-05-13 15:54:32.369  INFO 3878 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.u.mailOrder.util.MailConfigXML         : Getting mails from Wed May 13 15:51:30 CST 2020 to Wed May 13 15:54:32 CST 2020, it's 181 seconds. 
2020-05-13 15:54:32.374  INFO 3878 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.u.mailOrder.util.MailConfigXML         : Got 0 mail(s).
```

I've tried other mailbox, and found that those host can get mails and process them. 

**I wonder what may cause this?** Whether is the problem caused by the host of mailbox? How to avoid getting 0 mail?

Comment: What do you mean with "I've tried other hosts"?

Comment: @Titulum I tried other mailbox. For example my own mailbox.

Comment: Hello, I don't know if I am just interpreting the code wrong, but It seems like the time-span you use to search your emails did not result in any matches. Try to use a much wider time-span.

Comment: @FlorianHergenhahn That can be modified in config file. Some mailbox can successfully get mails so I don't think this is the criticle problem.

Comment: @萝莉w Do you want to get sent or received emails? Because you need to use different DateTerm's for this. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/search/ReceivedDateTerm.html

Comment: @FlorianHergenhahn I want to get the mails which was received and process them.

Comment: Try to change `SentDateTerm` to `ReceivedDateTerm` and see if it makes a difference. I am not sure if this is the solution but it might give better insight.

Comment: @FlorianHergenhahn Thanks, but it doesn't work.